# Reading one entire cell of a .csv file into a variable

Tags: c++, list, csv, file

There are three cells per line in a .csv file. I'm trying to read each cell into a private member variable of a class I have created. I cannot figure out how to read all of cell A1 into one string variable, then B1 into a double variable, and C3 into another separate double variable. I have played around with getline and overloading ostream operator >> but to no avail.

```
class LinkedTemp
{
private: 
// the struct that will temporarily hold all items being read from file
struct Govee
{
string date;
double temperature;
double humidity;
struct Govee *next;
};

Govee *head; // pointer to head of all ListNodes

string time;
double temp;
double humi;

public:
// default constructor 
// set private members 
LinkedTemp()
{
head = nullptr;

time = "";
temp = 0.0;
humi = 0.0;

}

void append()
{
Govee *nodePtr, *newNode = nullptr;

// create a newNode and fill it with data (node will then be appended)
newNode = new Govee;
newNode->date = this->time;
newNode->temperature = this->temp;
newNode->humidity = this->humi;
newNode->next = nullptr;    

// start at beginning of list
nodePtr = head;

// if list does not exist, make node the first node
if (!head)
head = newNode;


else
{
// traverse the list
while (nodePtr != nullptr)
    nodePtr = nodePtr->next;

// append newNode onto the end of the list
nodePtr->next = newNode;
}//end else statement

}//end append function


// supports 
// cout << object
friend ostream &operator << (ostream &strm, LinkedTemp &r)
{
strm << "Date: " << r.time << endl;
strm << "Temp: " << r.temp << endl;
strm << "Humi: " << r.humi << endl;
return strm;
}

// will fill all public member variables of class 
// file >> object
friend istream &operator >> (istream &strm, LinkedTemp &r)
{   
getline(strm, r.time);
strm >> r.temp;
strm >> r.humi;
return strm;
}

}; // end class
```

And in main I have something like:

```
int main()
{

//open file
fstream file;
file.open("Feb.csv");

// create LinkedTemp object
LinkedTemp list;

// read file into LinkedTemp object
// while (file)
//{
file >> list;
//}
// append the information into the list
// list.append();

// display all the contents of the list
cout << list;

return 0;
}
```

But I either read in the entire row or only the 2020-02-07 part of the .csv file and not the entire 2020-02-07 00:00:00. See attached image for format of the .csv file. [.csv File Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T4Cd.png)

Comment: First, the shown code calls getline. This reads the entire line into the `time`. All three values. Then the shown code uses the `>>` operator, on the input stream again. Does that make sense to you? So, first row in the csv file is in the string. That becomes "time". Instead the code uses `>>` to read whatever follows the first line, ***as whitespace-delimited words*** in the csv file. Grand total: first line read, becomes a string. `>>` reads two words after the first line which must be whitespace-delimited. The rest of the file is ignored. As Mr. Spock would say: this is highly illogical.

Comment: Could you indent your code? It's hard to read with everything in column 1.

Comment: @John Kugelman - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by storing all tokens in a `vector` of `vector` of `strings`. This will create a 2 dimensional string matrix which you can process anyway you like later on. Following code is what you need:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

struct data{
    std::string s0;
    double d0;
    double d1;
};

int main()
{
    // create a vector of your class to store all of your data, 
    // in your case it's a list so you can tweak it according to your needs
    std::vector <data> vec_data;
    // create a vector of vectors of strings to store all the tokens you read from file
    std::vector <std::vector<std::string>> vec_tokens;

    std::ifstream is("file.csv");
    if(is.is_open()) {
        std::string line;
        while(getline(is, line)) {
            std::stringstream ss_line(line);
            std::string token;
            std::vector <std::string> vec_temp;
            while(getline(ss_line, token, ',')) {
                vec_temp.push_back(token);
            }
            vec_tokens.push_back(vec_temp);
        }
    }

    // convert all tokens into data
    for(auto i: vec_tokens) {
        vec_data.push_back({i[0], std::stod(i[1]), std::stod(i[2])});   
    }

    // clean up tokens
    vec_tokens.clear();

    // check if it worked
    for(auto i: vec_data) {
        std::cout << i.s0 << " , " << i.d0 << " , " <<  i.d1    << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

You might need to handle exceptions (i.e. for `std::stod`) in case the program is given a garbage csv file.